# D3.Js Graph not loading

Tags: javascript, facebook, d3.js

I'm trying to load a D3.js graph to display a Facebook User's mutual friends after they log in through my localhost. The Facebook App is set-up correctly, as I can log in with a number of different accounts, but the D3.js graph doesn't load. Here's the code:

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://d3js.org/d3.v2.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript"    src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js">
    </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="friendgraph.js">        
    </script>
    <title>d3.js Facebook friend visualization</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="viz"></div>
    <div id="fb-root">
        <div id="selected-friend-name"></div>
        <div id="auth-status">
            <div id="auth-loggedout">
                <a href="#" id="auth-loginlink">Login</a>
            </div>
        <div id="auth-loggedin" style="display:none">
          Logged in as <span id="auth-displayname"></span>  
    (<a href="#" id="auth-logoutlink">logout</a>)
        </div>
        <div id="load-status"></div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Friendgraph.js:

```
// Facebook SDK

// Initialize the Facebook SDK
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
FB.init({
    appId: '109566779171141', // App ID
    version    : 'v2.2',
    status: true, // check login status
    cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    xfbml: true  // parse XFBML
});

// Listen for and handle auth.statusChange events
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', function(response) {
if (response.authResponse) {
    // On login...
    FB.api('/me', function(me) {
        if (me.name) {
            // Display user name
            document.getElementById('auth-displayname').innerHTML = me.name;
            // Retrieve friends API object
            FB.api('/me/friends', getFriends);
        }
    })
    document.getElementById('auth-loggedout').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('auth-loggedin').style.display = 'block';
} else {
    // User has not authorized your app or isn't logged in
    document.getElementById('auth-loggedout').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('auth-loggedin').style.display = 'none';
    }
    });

    // Respond to clicks on login and logout links
     document.getElementById('auth-loginlink').addEventListener('click', function()     {
    FB.login();
});
     document.getElementById('auth-logoutlink').addEventListener('click',     function(){
    FB.logout();
});
}

 function indexWithAttribute(array, attr, value) {
// Iterates over an array and returns the index of the element
// whose attribute matches the given value, or -1 if not found. 
for(var i=0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if(array[i][attr] === value) {
        return i;
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
    }
    }

 function showName(d) {
// Displays given d3 node's 'name' attribute.
document.getElementById('selected-friend-name').innerHTML = d['name'];
 }

function getMutualFriends(id, friends, friendlinks) {
// Retrieves a Facebook API object containing mutual friends
// for a given user ID. Passes it to the getLinks() function.
FB.api('/me/mutualfriends/' + id, function (response) {
    getLinks(response, id, friends, friendlinks); }
    );
 }

function getLinks(response, id, friends, friendlinks) {
// Calculates links between mutual friends and pushes them to an array.
// Displays percent of friend links completed in 'load-status' div. 
var mutualFriends = response['data'];
var sourceIndex = indexWithAttribute(friends, 'id', id);

var completed = Math.round(100*(sourceIndex/friends.length));

    document.getElementById('load-status').innerHTML = 'Calculating mutual friend  links: ' + completed + '%'    
for (i=0; i< mutualFriends.length; i++) {
        friends[sourceIndex]['value'] = mutualFriends.length;
             targetIndex = indexWithAttribute(friends, 'id', mutualFriends[i]    ['id']);
        friendlinks.push({'source':sourceIndex, 
                          'target':targetIndex,
                          'value':mutualFriends.length });
     }       

    if (sourceIndex === friends.length - 1) { 
    graphFriends(friends, friendlinks); }        
 }

 function getFriends(response) {
    // Loads friend nodes as an array. Creates array to hold links between mutual friends.
var friends = response['data']
var friendlinks = []

for (i=0; i < friends.length; i++) {
    var id = friends[i]['id'];
    getMutualFriends(id, friends, friendlinks);
    }
}

function graphFriends(friends, friendlinks) {
// Configures a d3 force-directed graph of friends and friend links.
document.getElementById('load-status').innerHTML = ''

// Set dimensions of svg
var width = window.innerWidth - 100,
    height = window.innerHeight - 100;

// Set up a 10-color scale for node colors
var color = d3.scale.category10()

// Set up a linear scale to map number of mutual
// friends to node radius
var r = d3.scale.linear()
            .domain([1,100])
            .range([5,15])

// Set the initial parameters of the force() layout
var force = d3.layout.force()
    .charge(-75)
    .linkDistance(40)
    .size([width / 1.2, height / 2])

// Add svg and start visualization
var svg = d3.select("#viz").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

// Pass in friends array as graph nodes and friendlinks
// array as graph edges.
force.nodes(friends)
    .links(friendlinks)
    .start();

var link = svg.selectAll("line.link")
    .data(friendlinks)
  .enter().append("line")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .style("stroke", "#eee")
    .style("stroke-width", 1);

var node = svg.selectAll("circle.node")
    .data(friends)
  .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("r", function(d) { return r(d.value); })
    .style("stroke", "#eee")
    .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.value); })
    .on("mouseover", function(d) { showName(d); })
    .call(force.drag);

force.on("tick", function() {
   link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
       .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
       .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
       .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

   node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
       .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
    });
 }
```

Any ideas what's wrong with it?

Edit:

When I call the response from the APi, I get the following:

```
Object {data: Array[0]}data: Array[0]length: 0__proto__: Array[0]concat:
```

plus a load more, so basically, I'm getting nothing back from the response. Anyone know why that would be? Has the Facebook API changed?

Comment: Do you get any error messages?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Nope. No error messages. The facebook login box appears, I login, it shows the name of the FB user, but then shows nothing else, no error message, no D3.js graph. Very confusing.

Comment: When you finally call `graphFriends(friends, friendlinks)`, what do `friends` and `friendlinks` look like?  Can you update your question with the contents of those variables?

Comment: @Mark Hi Mark, I've included what I'm getting back from the response, which is basically a blank array. Any ideas why this might be?

Comment: `user/mutual_friends` is deprecated for versions v2.0 and higher

Comment: @phwd Is there an alternative I can use? Or a way around it?

Comment: As long as you are using a v2.0+ application or using it beyond April, no there is way around it. If there was, it wouldn't be called a deprecation.